# django variable into input text value

Tags: python, django, html-input

I need to put the content of a django variable into an input type text value. The problem is that the django variable has two words and the input only shows the first one.

For example:

```
<input id="city" name="city" type="text" value={{ form.city.value }}>
{{ form.city.value }}
```

If form.city.value contains "New York", the input shows "New" and the second line shows "New York".

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work, I think you missed the quotes to wrap `{{ form.city.value }}`. Declare your input like this:

```
<input id="city" name="city" type="text" value="{{ form.city.value }}">
```

Hope it helps!